# How do I link within an object/array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to link users with their parents/children/spouses in same .js file

So, how do I 'link' within an object. Let say:

```
const users = {
  bradpitt: {
    name: "Brad",
    lastname: "Pitt",
    spouses: [{
      angelinajolie
    }]
  },
  angelinajolie: {
    name: "Angelina",
    lastname: "Jolie",
    parents: [{
      jonvoight
    }]
  }
  jonvoight: {
    name: "Jon"
  }
}
```

So I can use it like this:

```
getParents() {
  for (const u of users) {
    return u.parents.name
  }
}
```

Result: Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way, but missing some key features:

Take a look at the comments within this snippet!

> The main problem is the fact that you assign the object `angelinajolie` to `bradpitt` before the object `angelinejolie` is defined. An easier and more secure way to do this is with `id's` because names are not unique. I've used this in my example:

Also with properties you use a `for...in` loop and you need to check if the property is available. If `u.parents` is `undefined` it will throw an error.

I've changed the unique names to id numbers build with the string `id` and six digits. `id00000`. In the users object I simply refer to the user without the leading zeros and id. To rebuild this in the `getParents` function I've used `String.prototype.padStart`. It pads zeros to the left of the string until 6 characters are reached.

```
"id"+(p.toString().padStart(6, '0'));
```

```js
const users = {
  id000001 : {
    name: "Brad",
    lastname: "Pitt",
    spouses: [
      1
    ]
  },
  id000002 : {
    name: "Angelina",
    lastname: "Jolie",
    parents: [
      3 
    ]
  }, //fixed a missing comma here
  id000003: {
    name: "Jon"
  }
}


function getParents() {
  //define a return object
  //return parents per set of users
  const parents = {};
  //iterate over every user
  for (key in users) {
    const u = users[key];
    //if the user has parents go on
    if (u.parents)
    {
      //save the parents to parent object with the user as key:
      //use map to iterate over every parent and return the name of the parent
      parents[key] = u.parents.map((p) => users["id"+(p.toString().padStart(6, '0'))].name);
    }
  };
  //return the parents object
  return parents;
}

//log to console to show results:
console.log(getParents());
```